# JavaFX - How to send a variable from a controller to the Main class?

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx

----Revised draft----

I've been trying to create a game using JavaFX. In the game, a player sees a menu page at first("play game" ,"options","exit", etc), and he/she clicks the "OnlineGame" button to start a game.

And now I've already had a menu (created with fxml) and its controller.

```
<!-- MainMenu.fxml -->

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.media.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="MainMenuController">
   <children>  
        <Button fx:id="OnlineGame" layoutX="55.0" layoutY="157.0" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#OnlineGame" opacity="0.6" prefHeight="51.0" prefWidth="229.0" text="Play Online Game" textFill="#2067a1">
            <font>
        <Font size="21.0" />
            </font>
        </Button>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

The controller:

```
import *****;
//MainMenuController.java
public class MainMenuController{
@FXML private Button OnlineGame;

@FXML protected void OnlineGame(ActionEvent event) throws IOException{
    //start the game
}
}
```

The menu is initialized in Main.start and it works well.

```
import *****;
public class Main extends Application {
public void start(Stage Stage) {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("MainMenu.fxml"));
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,730,439); //set SceneSize
        Stage.setScene(scene);
        Stage.show();

        //call three methods to start a game
        prepareGame();
        addHandlers(scene);
        startGame();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void prepareGame(){**********}
private void addHandlers(Scene scene){***********}
private void startGame(){****}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

However, I also have some methods in Main.start to initialize a game.(prepareGame(); addHandlers(scene); startGame();). As you see, I also need to put them after stage.show;. So now the problem is that when I run my program, those three methods runs immediately (before I click my "OnlineGame" button in the menu!).

So are there any ways to achieve my goal(i.e. a player sees the game page after clicking "OnlineGame")?

PS: I simplified my code to make my question short(although it's still long :-D). I'm not a native speaker so if my words are confusing, please let me know so that I can explain it again. What's more, I'd like to post more details if necessary.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I thought about calling those three methods directly in Gamecontroller.java, but it doesn't work because I need to have "scene" in addHandlers(scene); .And I can't set them static methods because of some reasons

Comment: You just completely changed this question, after I had provided an answer.

Comment: Hi James_D! Thanks for your answer, I didn't know I could have a listener in my controller so I added my comment. Now I'll try it, and let you know if it works! btw, sorry for my misleading!

Comment: Please delete this question until you can decide what it is you want to ask. Right now you are justing wasting people's time.

Comment: Okay, thanks all the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move all that logic to the controller: it has no place in the `Application` class.

If you want those three method to only be invoked when the button is pressed, then the obvious thing to do is to invoke them from the button's handler method:

```
public class MainMenuController {

    @FXML
    private Button onlineGame ;

    @FXML
    private void onlineGame(ActionEvent event) {
        // button can't be pressed until it is in a scene, so getScene()
        // here cannot return null:
        addHandlers(game.getScene());
        prepareGame();
        startGame();
    }

    // ...
}
```

(Note that I changed the field and some method names so that they conform to standard Java [naming conventions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). You will need to change the FXML file to match these names.)

Comment: Thank you James. Yes there isn't enough place for the logic in the Main class, so my friend and I moved the logic out today and now the problem is fixed.